# What do you call the data wrapped inside a monad?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, terminology, monads

In speech and writing, I keep wanting to refer to the data inside a monad, but I don't know what to call it.

For example, in Scala, the argument to the function passed to `flatMap` gets bound to…er…that thing inside the monad. In:

```
List(1, 2, 3).flatMap(x => List(x, x))
```

`x` gets bound to that thing I don't have a word for.

Complicating things a bit, the argument passed to the Kleisli arrow doesn't necessarily get bound to *all* the data inside the monad. With `List`, `Set`, `Stream`, and lots of other monads, `flatMap` calls the Kleisli arrow many times, binding `x` to a different piece of the data inside the monad each time. Or maybe not even to "data", so long as the monad laws are followed. Whatever it is, it's wrapped inside the monad, and `flatMap` passes it to you without the wrapper, perhaps one piece at a time. I just want to know what to call the relevant inside-the-monad stuff that `x` refers to, at least in part, so I can stop mit all this fumbly language.

Is there a standard or conventional term for this thing/data/value/stuff/whatever-it-is?

If not, how about "the candy"?

Comment: I've always heard to it as the "value" of the Monad, though I'll concede that makes less sense when talking about `List`s and `Set`s.

Comment: Maybe "computed values" to go along with the "monadic computation" phrasing people use to talk about inhabitants of monadic types? I'm not aware of a more standard name, but not confident enough that I'm  aware of everything relevant to make this an actual answer...

Comment: Also in a wholly non-standard way, I have sometimes used "underlying values", in contrast to "monadic values" (and/or "functorial values"). "Computed values" sounds quite good, actually.

Comment: If I had to call it something, I would probably call it the _monadic state_ (or the _monad's state_), e.g. a `Maybe` can be in either `Just` (and contain a value) or `Nothing` state, and that state is the result of a monadic computation.  That resolves a little bit of the value/data hassle. However, since there's also the `State` monad, this might be a little bit confusing. Remark: Since there isn't a standard term for this, I believe that almost all answers will actually result in primary opinions.

Comment: @Zeta Indeed so far it's looking like there just isn't any well-known terminology for this. I hope we can leave the question up for at least a few days to give more people who've spent a long time in the functional-programming world a chance to chime in. Someone might know an authoritative but not-widely-known term, as sometimes happens. (Did you know that thing on the end of a shoelace that keeps it from unraveling is called an "aglet"? Hardly anybody does, but [shoelace experts](http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/aglets.htm) do.)

Comment: I've heard "contents", which is a nice kind of orthographic rhyme with the idea of monadic contexts.

Comment: @BenKovitz: Didn't know, on the other hand English isn't my first language ;). Also, I assume the answers to be primary opinion, although the question itself isn't. But after all, we're in the Haskell/Scala part of SO, which somehow seems to manage itself.

Comment: I would have suggested monand, as operand, but that's just a blue sky idea.  Otherwise, I'd stick with candy for all such -and or -andy notions.

Comment: @TravisBrown what goes with a context, what is woven with it, is the woof, which has the advantage (I say this as a dog person) that it is not a term overloaded in this context (pardon). "The woof here is a List of X." "The wolf?"  "No, the woof. Woof!"

Comment: Let me narrow your question down. If in `M[T]` `M` is referred to as "monad", how do you refer to `T`?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov `T` is the type of the thing that `x` gets bound to. This might be a crucial clue for extracting the terminology from the literature. There are actually two distinct concepts here, possibly with two terms, as illustrated by `Set`: the set of elements, and each individual element; `x` gets bound to the latter.

Comment: You didn't understand me. I didn't ask a question, I narrowed yours.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Thanks for the clarification. Now I see. I understand the thing inside the monad to be different than the type of that thing, so this would not be narrowing my question but changing it to something else. Of course, maybe I'm using the terminology or even the concepts confusedly or incorrectly. I would accept any sort of clarification of the terms for what is what here, even if not exactly what I asked for.

Comment: A "leaf" or "free variable".

Answer (score 16):

Trying to say "`x` gets bound to" is setting you up for failure. Let me explain, and guide you towards a better way of expressing yourself when talking about these sorts of things.

Suppose we have:

```
someList.flatMap(x => some_expression)
```

If we know that someList has type `List[Int]`, then we can safely say that **inside of some_expression, `x` is bound to a value of type `Int`.** Notice the caveat, "inside of some_expression". This is because, given `someList = List(1,2,3)`, `x` will take on the values of each of them: `1`, `2`, and `3`, in turn.

Consider a more generalized example:

```
someMonadicValue.flatMap(x => some_expression)
```

If we know nothing about `someMonadicValue`, then we don't know much about how `some_expression` is going to be invoked. It may be run once, or three times (as in the above example), or lazily, or asynchronously, or it may be scheduled for once someMonadicValue is finished (e.g. futures), or it may never be used (e.g. empty list, None). The Monad interface does not include reasoning about when or how `someExpression` will be used. So all you can say about what `x` will be is confined to the context of `some_expression`, *whenever* and *however* `some_expression` happens to be evaluated.

So back to the example.

```
someMonadicValue.flatMap(x => some_expression)
```

You are trying to say "`x` is the ??? of `someMonadicValue`." And you are looking for the word that accurately replaces ???. Well I'm here to tell you that you're doing it wrong. If you want to speak about `x`, then either do it

1. Within the context of `some_expression`. In this case, use the bolded phrase I gave you above: "inside of some_expression, `x` is bound to a value of type `Foo`." Or, alternatively, you can speak about `x`...
2. With additional knowledge about which monad you're dealing with.

In case #2, for example, for `someList.flatMap(x => some_expression)`, you could say that "`x` is each element of `someList`." For `someFuture.flatMap(x => some_expression)`, you could say that "`x` is the successful future value of `someFuture`, if it indeed ever completes and succeeds."

You see, that's the beauty of Monads. **That ??? that you are trying to describe, is the thing which the Monad interface abstracts over**. Now do you see why it's so difficult to give ??? a name? It's because it has a different name and a different meaning for each particular monad. And *that's the point* of having the Monad abstraction: to unify these differing concepts under the same computational interface.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm definitely not an expert in functional programming terminology and I expect that the following will not be an answer to your question from your point of view. To me the problem rather is: If choosing a term requires expert knowledge, so does understanding.*

Choosing an appropriate term largely depends on:

- your desired level of linguistic correctness, and
- your audience, and the corresponding connotations of certain terms.

Regarding the linguistic correctness the question is whether you properly want to refer to the values/data that are bound to `x`, or whether you can live with a certain (incorrect) abstraction. In terms of the audience, I would mainly differentiate between an audience with a solid background in functional programming and an audience coming from other programming paradigms. In case of the former, choosing the term is probably not entirely crucial, since the concept itself is familiar, and many terms would lead to the right association. The discussion in the comments already contains some very good suggestions for this case. However, the discussion also shows that you need a certain background in functional programming to see the rationale behind some terms.

For an audience without a background in functional programming, I would rather sacrifice linguistic correctness in favor of comprehensibility. In such a situation I often just refer to it as "underlying type", just to avoid any confusion that I would probably create by trying to refer to the "thing(s) in the monad" itself. Obviously, it is literally wrong to say "`x` is bound to the underlying type". However, it is more important to me that my audience understands a concept at all. Since most programmers are familiar with containers and their underlying types, I'm aiming for the (flawed) association "underlying type" => "the thing(s) that are in a container" => "the thing(s) inside a monad", which often seems to work.

**TL;DR:** There always is a trade-off between correctness and accessibility. And when it comes to functional programming, it is sometimes helpful to shift the bias towards the latter.

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` does not call the Kleisli arrow many times. And "that thing" is not "inside" the monad.

`flatMap` lifts a Kleisli arrow to the monad. You could see this as the *construction* of an arrow `M[A] => M[B]` between types (`A`, `B`) lifted to the monad (`M[A]`, `M[B]`), given a Kleisli arrow `A => M[B]`.

So `x` in `x => f(x)` is the value being lifted.

Answer (score 1):

What data?

```
data Monady a = Monady
```

Values of monads are values of monads, their wrapped type may be entirely a fiction. Which is to say that talking about it as if it exists may cause you pain.

What you want to talk about are the continuations like `Monad m => a -> m b` as they are guaranteed to exist. The funny stuff occurs in how `(>>=)` *uses* those continuations.

Answer (score 0):

**'Item'** seems good?  **'Item parameter'** if you need to be more specific.

Either the source data can contain multiple items, or the operation can call it multiple times. *Element* would tend to be more specific for the first case, *Value* is singular as to the source & not sensible for list usages, but *Item* covers all cases correctly.

Disclaimer:  I know more about understandable English than about FP.

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back here.

A monad isn't just the functor `m` that wraps a value `a`.  A monad is the stack of endofunctors (i.e., the compositions of `m`'s), together with the `join` operator.  That's where the famous quip -- that a monad is a monoid in the category of endofunctors, what's the problem? -- comes from.

(The whole story is that the quip means the composition of `m`'s is another `m`, as witnessed by `join`)

A thing with the type `(m a)` is typically called a monad action.  You can call `a` the *result* of the action.